# How does Backbone.$ get set in CommonJS modules configuration?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I was going through the Backbone.js source code copied below from http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js

```
(function(root, factory) {

  // Set up Backbone appropriately for the environment. Start with AMD.
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['underscore', 'jquery', 'exports'], function(_, $, exports) {
      // Export global even in AMD case in case this script is loaded with
      // others that may still expect a global Backbone.
      root.Backbone = factory(root, exports, _, $);
    });

  // Next for Node.js or CommonJS. jQuery may not be needed as a module.
  } else if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    var _ = require('underscore');
    factory(root, exports, _);

  // Finally, as a browser global.
  } else {
    root.Backbone = factory(root, {}, root._, (root.jQuery || root.Zepto || root.ender || root.$));
  }

}(this, function(root, Backbone, _, $) {

  // Initial Setup
  // -------------

  // Save the previous value of the `Backbone` variable, so that it can be
  // restored later on, if `noConflict` is used.
  var previousBackbone = root.Backbone;

  // Create local references to array methods we'll want to use later.
  var array = [];
  var push = array.push;
  var slice = array.slice;
  var splice = array.splice;

  // Current version of the library. Keep in sync with `package.json`.
  Backbone.VERSION = '1.1.2';

  // For Backbone's purposes, jQuery, Zepto, Ender, or My Library (kidding) owns
  // the `$` variable.
  Backbone.$ = $;
```

In the CommonJS/node.js configuration, it says `Next for Node.js or CommonJS. jQuery may not be needed as a module.` and calls `factory(root, exports, _)` with the fourth `$` param for jquery as undefined. In the factory function it goes `Backbone.$ = $` so `Backbone.$` would be undefined? Then wouldn't a lot of stuff (AJAX, `$el` wrapping, etc.) break?

Comment: Yes, a lot of stuff breaks. To fix that you have to use `backbone.$ = require("jquery");`.

Comment: @Peruggia How come it doesn't just do that internally (It is using a `jquery` dep for the AMD configuration)? Is that just cause in the AMD configuration you can define `jquery` to be whatever jquery-like library you're using but with the CommonJS module you'd require `jquery.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason to use jQuery is to work with DOM manipulation, and that is useless in the back end(nodejs) so there is no need to load that as a dependency. To solve this problem you can create a simple module that returns the BackboneJS with jQuery.

```
// libs/backbone.js
var backbone = require("backbone");
backbone.$ = require("jquery");
module.exports = backbone;
```

Comment: That's not entirely true, or it's entirely subjective. Backbone.Model also uses `$.ajax` which is essential for `.save`, `.fetch`, etc.. etc. This has nothing to do with DOM manipulation.